# Java "scheduleAtFixedRate" alternative solution?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a Java application that is used to communicate with an embedded device over a UART connection (RS422).    The host queries the microcontroller for data in 5 millisecond intervals.  Up until recently I've been using ScheduledExecutorService scheduleAtFixedRate to call my communication protocol method, but it turns out scheduleAtFixedRate is very unreliable for this desired level of precision (as many other posts reveal).  Among the data returned from the microcontroller is a timestamp (in microseconds), allowing me to verify the interval between received data packets independently of the JVM.  Needless to say, the interval when using scheduleAtFixedRate varied wildly - up to 30 milliseconds between packets.  Additionally, the scheduler will then try to overcompensate for the missed cycles by calling the Runnable several times within one millisecond (again, no surprise to anyone here).

After some searching, there seemed to be a consensus that the JVM simply could not be trusted to ensure any kind of precise scheduling.  However, I decided to do some experimenting on my own and came up with this:

```
Runnable commTask = () -> {
    // volatile boolean controlled from the GUI
    while(deviceConnection) {
        // retrieve start time
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        // time since commProtocol was last called
        timeDiff = startTime - previousTime;

        // if at least 5 milliseconds has passed
        if(timeDiff >= 5000000) {
            // handle communication
            commProtocol();
            // store the start time for comparison
            previousTime = startTime;
        }
    }
};

// commTask is started as follows
service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.schedule(commTask, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The result of this was fantastic.  Adjacent timestamps never varied by more than 0.1 milliseconds from the expected 5 millisecond interval.  Despite this, something about this technique doesn't seem right, but I haven't been able to come up with anything else that works.  My question is basically whether or not this approach is OK, and if not, what should I do instead?

(I am running Windows 10 with JDK 8_74)

Comment: Your solution may use a lot of the processor; you might want to add a tiny sleep into the while loop in order to free up resources.

Comment: You might get a good answer here, but you could also try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I wonder how reliable `sleep` is for millisecond intervals, @Vulcan. It seems like Ben needs to avoid uncertainty that would be trivial in other applications, e.g. 30 ms.

Comment: Here is a meaty article you may enjoy, Ben: [Developing Real-Time Software with Java SE APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/nilsen-realtime-pt1-2264405.html) (article from 2014), which references the Real-Time Specification for Java (JSR 1) and Safety Critical Java Technology specification (JSR 302).

Comment: Thanks David.  Also, if I decide to post this on the codereview site, do I need to delete it from here, or is it ok to have duplicates?  I quickly scanned through the help section but didn't find any rules regarding that.

Comment: I don't think there are any rules against duplicates. The sites do have different purposes, but I think a question like yours could be answered from different perspectives, and any qualms on either side could probably be resolved by a bit of rewording.

Comment: What you've got there looks similar to the main loop of a computer game engine. Which means your solution is good. Add a Thread.sleep(0) to allow other processes the opportunity to breath, change the executor to Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor, and you have a typical fast-performing, throttled, yielding main loop.

Comment: SteveMcLeod post this as an answer and I'll accept it (I ended up substituting Thread.yield instead).

Comment: David, I read the article and came to the conclusion that the only other solution would involve purchasing real-time java, as this doesn't really work as a soft real time application - an interesting read nonetheless.

Comment: Could you flip the problem and have the embedded device send down the wire the data every 5ms? I'd wager it's less busy and in more predictable way than general purpose Windows 10. Depending on the platform they often have high resolution timers and timer triggered interrupts which could then trigger your sending routine. Your PC then can receive it all from some buffer and any jitter here would not matter that much. Otherwise you are looking at JAVA on any RTOS or https://www.aicas.com/cms/en/jamaicavm-pe  (both commercial). Finally making your Java program garbage free is an option.

Comment: @diginoise I have done that on an earlier protocol I developed and it worked pretty well.  The reason I decided to switch to the PC initiating transmissions was because I wanted the protocol to work for RS485 networks with multiple devices as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information I've received in the comments, I've decided to use leave my code essentially intact (with the exception of Thread.yield() which I've added to the while loop).  I have used this for a few months now and am very satisfied with the performance from this approach.  See the final code below.

```
Runnable commTask = () -> {
    // volatile boolean controlled from the GUI
    while(deviceConnection) {
        // retrieve start time
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        // time since commProtocol was last called
        timeDiff = startTime - previousTime;

        // if at least 5 milliseconds has passed
        if(timeDiff >= 5000000) {
            // handle communication
            commProtocol();
            // store the start time for comparison
            previousTime = startTime;
        }
        Thread.yield();
    }
};

// commTask is started as follows
service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.execute(commTask);
```